# boost doxygen documentation

Tags: c++, boost, doxygen

I have been trying to generate doxygen documentation for boost, as a way to browse source tree and have man documentation.
However, doxygen has been running for past week or so on IBM power5, and I have no idea how much longer (right now I am on `boost_1_43_0/boost/mpl/`).

Is there prebuilt doxygen documentation, if not, is there any way to speed up documentation generation without losing cross-referencing in code browser?

I have been using older documentation located on tena-sda, but that is quite old.

thank you

Comment: What's wrong with [online documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/index.html)?

Comment: @Kirill no source code cross-reference and no man pages

Answer (score 1):

I agree with you. However, doxygen ***cannot parse*** the complexity of C++ that Boost utilizes. Best bet is for you to grock (search) the source with a powerful IDE.

Comment: That's right. I've tried to run doxygen on it, and it crashes. Doxygen is pretty fine w.r.t other huge code bases though, but boost doesn't really live in the same universe as most other libraries. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Even if it was working using `doxygen` to browse a source code is not really relevant. Here are two alternatives that I use daily :

1. `grep` is your friend ! It is very efficient and fast to find what you want in a source code, even if this one is large
2. Make development with an IDE that support live parsing like NetBeans, then you will have cross-references inside your whole code, even across libraries (like Boost) that it uses, inside the editor itself.